# More 'Pythonic' Way to alternate list shuffle

Tags: python, list

Trying to 'shuffle' a list with even number of items. Splitting the list, `L` in half and alternating taking an element from each.

I've tried `pop`, but that approach was unable to get me to a one-liner. (`while` loop) and I know there is likely some more succinct way to move through it.

The `shuffle` from `random` isn't exactly what I need, either – because that randomizes the entire order instead of alternating between the split list.

If a one-liner isn't possible, is that because it's more readable in a `while` loop?

```
def shuffle(L):
    '''
    I apologize in advance for how wet the following code is... 
    Example:
    >>> shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
    [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
    '''
    return [L[:(len(L)//2)][0], L[(len(L)//2):][0], L[:(len(L)//2)][1], L[(len(L)//2):][1], L[:(len(L)//2)][2], L[(len(L)//2):][2]]
```

other attempt:

```
def shuffle(L):
    x, L_first, L_next, L = len(L), L[:(len(L)//2)], L[(len(L)//2):], []
    while len(L) != x:
        L.extend([L_first.pop(0), L_next.pop(0)])
    return L
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use slice assignment with a step:

```
def shuffle(l):
    result = [None] * len(l)

    # Put the first half of l in the even indices of result
    result[::2] = l[:len(l)//2]

    # Put the second half of l in the odd indices of result
    result[1::2] = l[len(l)//2:]

    return result
```

Comment: I haven't seen the `[None]` used before. Does this make an empyt list with `len(l)` empty spaces?

Comment: @be-ns: It makes a list with `len(l)` references to the `None` object. These are not empty spaces, but `None` makes a good filler.

Comment: that's clever. I'll have to start using that.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you could also opt for [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) after zipping to get the alternating effect.

```
from itertools import chain

def shuff(l):
    return list(chain.from_iterable(zip(l[:len(l)//2], l[len(l)//2:])))
```

**Demo**

```
>>> shuff(list(range(1, 7))
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Comment: I'll have to dig into this more to make sure I get this, but it works perfectly even on much longer lists. @Mitch

Answer (score 2):

One possibility (requires an external library but the recipe can also be found in the [`itertools`-recipes section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes)) is:

```
from iteration_utilities import roundrobin

def shuffle(L):
    return list(roundrobin(L[:len(L)//2], L[len(L)//2:]))
```

This is probably slower than list assignment but it also works for arbitary amounts of iterables without problems and it doesn't require odd-sized-input handling:

```
>>> shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
>>> shuffle([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

---

I did some [timings](https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/c0dfd2c07ca2ffcd35f7384380f08a37) and @user2357112 definetly has the fastest solution but my solution is at least on the second place (note that this graph is in log-log, that means the difference in absolute terms may seem smaller than it really is!):

[image]

---

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm the author of that `iteration_utilities` library.</sup>

Comment: how well does it hold up when the list is, say, 1000 items instead of 6? `roundrobin` looks like the perfect recipe, (like zip but to a list instead of two-tuples).

Comment: @be-ns That will depend on which function you use (the one from `iteration_utilities` or the one from the `itertools` recipes section) and on which python version. I'll add some benchmarks :)

Comment: @be-ns I've updated the answer and included the timings.

Comment: @MSeifert This graph is cool. Can you tell me how it was made? And how are you getting the timings? Thanks :)

Comment: @KingMak https://gist.github.com/MSeifert04/c0dfd2c07ca2ffcd35f7384380f08a37 (also linked inside the answer)

Comment: oh my apology, did not pay attention to that link. Thanks

Comment: No problem. However it requires matplotlib (for the plot) and ipython (for the magic `%timeit`):) And I probably forgot to include the code for creating the image (however if you want to display it, you can simply use `plt.show()` at the end).

Answer (score 1):

list comprehension with index calculation using modulo and floor division

```
[ L[(i + (i % 2)*len(L))//2] for i in range(len(L)) ] # for case of even len(L)
```

still one line for the general case

```
[ L[i//2 + (i % 2)*len(L)//2] for i in range(2*(len(L)//2)) ] + [L[-1]]*(len(L) % 2)
```

the index calc `(i + (i % 2)*len(L))//2`

can be parsed as adding

`i//2` which gives `0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2 ...`

and

`(i % 2)*len(L)//2` where `(i % 2)` alternates 0, 1 for even/odd `i`

`0, len(L)//2, 0, len(L)//2, 0, len(L)//2 ...`

sum:

`0, len(L)//2, 1, 1 + len(L)//2, 2, 2 + len(L)//2 ...`

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion

Comment: Can you break it down a little bit? I can't understand what is happening

Answer (score 0):

Found two solutions. First one is very unpythonic (using python 2.7)

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6] # intial array
```

Method One (using string magic):

```
[int(p) for p in ' '.join([str(x) + ' ' + str(y) for x, y in zip(a[:len(a) / 2], a[len(a) / 2:])]).split(' ')]
```

Method Two:

```
[i for Tuple in zip(a[:len(a) / 2], a[len(a) / 2:]) for i in Tuple]
```